# Download video from a website which requires login and doesn't have URL

Tags: video, download, blob

**I have a video URL (https://www.time4education.com/my/videotest.php?videoid=a7df487a87424bf3b4a6c6768fe96c78) extracted from chrome's Developer's tools.**

UPDATE:- the video address is blob file but i couldn't find any m3u8 file,however there is a .mpd file( as per other stack answers)

This URL is only accessible until I login in other words if I directly try to access this, it needs to authenticate and then view this.

```
Now my problem is that I want to download this video either through a python script or any other way ( youtube-dl).
```

Note:- Previous answers on stack didn't solve my problem.
[How to download video from any website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49899939/13126651)
[Download from sites that require a login using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63931525/13126651)
[How do we download a blob url video](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42901942/13126651)

Comment: Which programming language are you using... JavaScript on developer console?

Comment: Besides, if you did your research, why don't you post the links to those answers?

Comment: yes, let me edit

Comment: updated my answer, can you suggest me a way on how to tackle this problem

Comment: Still, I think that the question is off-topic (not specific to programming) for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901942/how-do-we-download-a-blob-url-video is closed.

Comment: why don't you suggest me on how to tackle through python or any other programming so that it's not off-topic?

Comment: ... while you could ask for how to download it with Python->selenium/puppetter/phantom js (I don't claim that I'm good at these things), they might be a cumbersome way to do the task (and you need to provide a [example], which you didn't have in this case) -- perhaps asking on superuser is better (again I'm not very familiar with that site, can't tell if it's ontopic there) -- anyway does opening the URL in a new tab work?

Comment: if i am already logged in, then it does not ask for my credentials otherwise it does not ask for credentials directly opens the video

Comment: Then can't you simply download the video with the browser from that link?

Comment: No, there is no option even i tried chrome extensions but no luck however i found out that there is .mpd file